# UnboundLocalError: Local Variable Referenced Before Assignment in Python/Docker

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, containers, gdal

I am attempting to run a simple Python script to print/write the name of a GeoTIFF within a local Desktop directory, after building a docker container image.  The script executes and produces the desired output as a standalone script, but when I attempt to run the docker container image via a "docker run" command I get an error that states a variable is "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'rows' referenced before assignment".  I am not sure why it shows this error when running the container yet runs as a standalone script.  Below is my Dockerfile, along with the script itself.

The Dockerfile

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3

ADD docker_test.py .

RUN /opt/conda/bin/conda install gdal=3.0.2

CMD [ "python", "./docker_test.py" ]
```

The Python script (docker_test.py)

```
import glob
from osgeo import gdal

def image_processing():

    for file in glob.glob("*.tif"): # points to image located in the directory for parsing
        dem = gdal.Open(file)
        rows = dem.RasterYSize
        cols = dem.RasterXSize
 
  return rows, cols

rows, cols = image_processing()

with open('gdal_docker_test.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(f'The number of rows is: {rows}')
```

I feel as if it should be a simple fix, but I just cannot figure out the tweak.  Any assistance is most appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If nothing is returned from `glob.glob("*.tif")`, then the `row` object is never created.

Please also note that your version will only return the `rows, cols` for the last file.

The modified version below will hopefully help highlight the issue.

```py
import glob
from osgeo import gdal

def image_processing():
    files = glob.glob("*.tif"): # points to image located in the directory for parsing

    if not files:
        raise FileNotFoundError("*.tif file not found in: {}".format(glob.glob("*")))
    else:
        for file in files:
            print(file)
            dem = gdal.Open(file)
            rows = dem.RasterYSize
            cols = dem.RasterXSize
        return rows, cols

rows, cols = image_processing()

with open('gdal_docker_test.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(f'The number of rows is: {rows}')
```

A minimally modified version:

```py
import glob
from osgeo import gdal

def image_processing():
    rows = -1
    cols = -1

    for file in glob.glob("*.tif"): # points to image located in the directory for parsing
        dem = gdal.Open(file)
        # This code is never reached in your example because the image isnt' found.
        rows = dem.RasterYSize
        cols = dem.RasterXSize
 
    return rows, cols

rows, cols = image_processing()

with open('gdal_docker_test.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(f'The number of rows is: {rows}')
```

Comment: Kapocsi - Thank you for pointing this out, but this was actually an error in my original post (now updated) and not in the code itself.  Your suggested edit is actually what my script shows and successfully runs as a standalone file, but no when run within the docker container.  I believe it is something specific to Docker that I cannot figure out, thanks again for your insights!

Comment: I understand. However, my point about the row object never being created remains relevant. Your program cannot find your image file and is trying to return/reference the image dimensions before they are created/initialized. Please see the modified version above.

Comment: Kapocsi - Thank you for clarifying, I think we are getting closer the solution.  Your edit did raise the flag that my script cannot find the image file within the container via "FileNotFoundError: *.tif file not found in: ['home', 'srv', 'etc', 'opt', 'root', 'lib', 'mnt', 'usr', 'media', 'lib64', 'sys', 'dev', 'sbin', 'boot', 'bin', 'run', 'proc', 'tmp', 'var', 'docker_test.py']"  My .tif file is located in a local desktop folder which is bound to the container, so I'm not sure why it cannot find the file.  Perhaps it is missing other dependencies with GDAL?  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Need more information about how your docker container is invoked. That is a separate issue/question. Please see the docs for more info: https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/